# How does rxjs work in terms of Threads

Tags: angular, multithreading, rxjs, observable

I am currently using building an angular2 application where I am using rxjs. I am in need of using Observables with promises and interval. I am now trying to understand what consequences they pose from a Threading perspective.

Consider the following code bit for a service that would be injected into a component,

```
import { interval } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
    observable: any;

    constructor() {
        this.observable = interval(1000);

        this.observable.subscribe( (x) =>
            //Do something every 1000 seconds
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how the polling every 1000 milliseconds would work in terms of Thread generation. Is there a separate thread created that keeps track of the polling via subscribers?

It would be great if I could get a generalized view on how to relate threads to scenarios involving Observables and how blocking is avoided.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. There aren't multiple threads involved; just an event loop.

Comment: General view: no threads.

Comment: There is a very simple answer: there are no threads at all, all of JavaScript is monothreaded. Except with ServiceWorkers and similar, but that's not widely used yet (modern browsers only).
In other terms, when the "do something" part is executed, whatever was running at the time is stopped, then resumed with the task ends.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, it does indeed help me! It would be great if you could direct me to an article where I can read about this and ServiceWorkers etc

Answer (score -2):

try

```
this.observable.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(1000)
  .subscribe(value =>  {
  });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! If you append an explanation why your suggestion would answer the authors question it might become relevant. Merely providing code is the `give a man a fish and he eats for a day` of coding.

Comment: Thank you for your response, again it would be great if you could let me know what I am looking for by trying the code. Thank you!